# Getting the alt attribute of an image in prototype

Tags: javascript, image, prototypejs

I'm editing some old sideshow code someone else written a while ago and I was wondering how you get the alt attribute of an image with prototype.

Ive got the image tag selected with the code below:

```
$$('#' + this.slides[this.currentSlide].id + ' a img')
```

But for the life of me I don't know how to get the alt text.

I've tried...

```
$$('#' + this.slides[this.currentSlide].id + ' a img').alt;
$$('#' + this.slides[this.currentSlide].id + ' a img').alt();
$$('#' + this.slides[this.currentSlide].id + ' a img').readAttribute('alt');
```

Could anyone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$$` [utility method](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar) returns an array. You need to get the element out of the array and then read its attribute.

```
var elements = $$('#' + this.slides[this.currentSlide].id + ' a img');
if (elements.length > 0) {
   var altText = elements[0].readAttribute('alt');
   alert(altText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cheers, this worked for me:

```
$$('#' + this.slides[this.currentSlide].id + ' a img')[0].alt
```